# Black hole gun Stick fight: the game

Tags: stick-fight-the-game

In the steam game, Stick Fight: The Game, there is black hole weapons.

How do we get them?

Comment: You could probably clarify what black hole weapons are.

Answer (score 1):

All weapons in SFTG spawn randomly.